# Insensitive column names in Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am looping using .NET code in tables of similar structure. All the tables have the column "JOBDATECLOSED" but in some tables it appears as "JobDateClosed", in others as "jobdateclosed" or "jobDateClosed". My query fails when the hardcoded "JOBDATECLOSED" loops into tables where the column name appears in a different case (lowercase or uppercase). Is there a way to avoid that in Oracle?

```
Query
Select COUNT(*) FROM "tableX" WHERE lower("JOBDATECLOSED") IS NOT NULL

Code
Dim cmdInside As New OracleCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM """ & drTablesOracle.Item("TABLE_NAME") & """ WHERE ""jobDateClosed"" IS NOT NULL", conSCoracle)
```

*I know how to make the whole system case insensitive but I'm not interested into that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name and column name are case-sensitive because your are putting quotes around them, which tells Oracle to be case-sensitive. Try not putting the quotes around the name.

```
Select COUNT(*) FROM tableX WHERE lower(JOBDATECLOSED) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The problem is for tables that are imported in lower case such as step_factor_20120903 with column jobDateClosed when I query like: Select COUNT(*) FROM step_factor_20120903 WHERE jobDateClosed IS NOT NULL, I get an error: Error starting at line : 107 in command -
Select COUNT(*) FROM step_factor_20120903 WHERE jobDateClosed IS NOT NULL
Error at Command Line : 107 Column : 22
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: But when you put the table name and field name in quotes, the same SQL works?

Comment: Very strange. I am a little confused because you were asking about case insensitive column names yet the error says it cannot find the table. Does `Select COUNT() FROM step_factor_2012090` return without error?

Comment: yes, the tables columns were structured as "jobdateclosed" when they were imported from SQL Server. Your answer is correct